# Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, google-play-services

I am trying to build a signed Apk of my project and i get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzv$zza$zza.class
```

When I choose the debug build type I got no errors and everything works fine. I searched for a while to fix this but i found nothing useful.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.danielsous.demos"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

}


dependencies {
compile files('libs/scanditsdk-android-4.7.5.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.github.attenzione:android-ColorPickerPreference:e3aa301016'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```

The other build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You expect us to use our wizardry skill to find out why you face that without even sharing your code for us to debug it for you because you lack of initiative?

Comment: Noted, but could you explain the issue in chronology at least we could guide you.

Answer (score 1):

I had 1 library and a second library made from an aar file which contained multiple resource with the same names ( pngs files with same names, strings with the same ids, layouts with the same files ). Removing the aar library fixed my issues

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have more than one libraries added for printHelper.

Every time that you face a duplicate entry error run ./gradlew app:dependencies and make sure that there is no duplicated versions of a same module.